# pexpect not waiting for the command to get completed

Tags: python

```
import pexpect

ssh_address = '172.18.15.50'
ssh_username = 'admin'
ssh_password = 'ctesla#123'
ssh_port = 22

def check_power_status(PDU_IP, PDU_Username, PDU_Password, outlet):
    print("Trying to establish SSH connection.")
    ssh_command = f"ssh {ssh_username}@{ssh_address} -p {ssh_port}"
    ssh_session = pexpect.spawn(ssh_command, encoding='utf-8')
    ssh_session.expect('password: ')
    ssh_session.sendline(ssh_password)
    ssh_session.expect('>')
    print("SSH connection established.")

    print(f"Sending 'telnet {PDU_IP}' and waiting for 'Username:'")
    ssh_session.sendline(f"telnet {PDU_IP}")
    ssh_session.expect('Username:')

    print(f"Sending '{PDU_Username}' and waiting for 'Password:'")
    ssh_session.sendline(PDU_Username)
    ssh_session.expect('Password:')

    print(f"Sending '{PDU_Password}' and waiting for 'Welcome'")
    ssh_session.sendline(PDU_Password)
    ssh_session.expect('#')

    print(f"Sending 'show outlets {outlet}' and waiting for 'Power state:'")
    ssh_session.sendline(f"show outlets {outlet}")
    ssh_session.expect("Power state:")
    command_output = ssh_session.before
    if "Power state: On" in command_output:
        print("Device is ON state")
        return 1
    elif "Power state: Off" in command_output:
        print("Device is OFF state")
        return 0
    else:
        print("Device is in UNKNOWN state")
        print(command_output)
        return -1

check_power_status('10.6.141.66', 'admin', 'admin', "13")
```

Logs:

```
Trying to establish SSH connection.
SSH connection established.
Sending 'telnet 10.6.141.66' and waiting for 'Username:'
Sending 'admin' and waiting for 'Password:'
Sending 'admin' and waiting for 'Welcome'
Sending 'show outlets 13' and waiting for 'Power state:'
Device is in UNKNOWN state
                                                                               #                                                                               show outlets 13                                                               show outlets 13                                                               how outlets 13                                                               how outlets 13                                                               
Outlet 13: 13 (no name)                                                         Outlet 13: 13 (no name)                                                         


Process finished with exit code 0
```

For the last command `(show outlets {outlet})`:

1. It says it has found a match with `Power state:`, but when I print it, it does not have that string.
2. How to send the command and make sure it executes it and makes sure it's complete by checking that `Power state:` is present in the output and it ends with #
3. Any other option present to achieve this?

Manual operation:

```
Login for PX2 CLI
Username: admin
Password:

Welcome to PX2 CLI!
Last login: 2000-12-30 15:44:01 EST [CLI (Telnet) from 10.6.1.33]

# show outlets 13
Outlet 13: 13 (no name)
Power state: On

#
```